# SSIS error when Execute a Package but Works fine when Execute as a task

Tags: c#, ssis, dynamics-crm

I encountered a strange error in my SSIS Script Component. So I have a Package with several Tasks inside it. My Package job is to get data from Dynamic CRM 365 using Script Component and CRM SDK Assembly that I already registered in GAC. Now the problem is when I running my Task as a whole package it will return some error that strangely doesn't appear when I execute it as a Task. the problem is I can't debug it because when it hit the breakpoint my job doesn't return any error. So this error only return when I tried to execute as Package and doesn't have a breakpoint. the error says something like this
`The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.`

Here is the full code from my Script Component,

```
public override void InputToken_ProcessInputRow(InputTokenBuffer Row)
    {
        /*
         * Add your code here
         */
        IOrganizationService service = null;
        do
        {
            service = CRMService.CRMConnect(Variables.userNameCRM, Variables.passwordCRM, Variables.serviceURLCRM);
            if (service != null)
            {
                RetrieveEntityChangesRequest retrieveEntityChanges = new RetrieveEntityChangesRequest();
                retrieveEntityChanges.Columns = new ColumnSet(true);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.Changetoken))
                {
                    retrieveEntityChanges.DataVersion = Row.Changetoken;
                }

                Id = Row.Id;

                retrieveEntityChanges.EntityName = "opportunity";
                retrieveEntityChanges.PageInfo = new PagingInfo();




                RetrieveEntityChangesResponse retrieveResponse = (RetrieveEntityChangesResponse)service.Execute(retrieveEntityChanges);

                ChangeToken = retrieveResponse.EntityChanges.DataToken;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ChangeToken))
                {
                    OutputTokenBuffer.AddRow();
                    OutputTokenBuffer.Id = Id;
                    OutputTokenBuffer.NewToken = ChangeToken;

                }

                foreach (var entity in retrieveResponse.EntityChanges.Changes)
                {


                    if (entity.Type == ChangeType.NewOrUpdated)
                    {
                        var newUpdatedEntity = ((NewOrUpdatedItem)entity).NewOrUpdatedEntity;

                        OutputOdataNewUpdateBuffer.AddRow();

                        OutputOdataNewUpdateBuffer.CompanyId = "FCEBAF24-90A3-4DDB-A38D-40BADCA5C993";

                        if (newUpdatedEntity.Attributes.ContainsKey("createdon"))
                            OutputOdataNewUpdateBuffer.CreatedDate = newUpdatedEntity.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("createdon");


                        if (newUpdatedEntity.Attributes.ContainsKey("kdi_opportunitynumber"))
                            OutputOdataNewUpdateBuffer.OpportunityNumber = newUpdatedEntity.GetAttributeValue<string>("kdi_opportunitynumber").ToString();

                        if (newUpdatedEntity.Attributes.ContainsKey("name"))
                            OutputOdataNewUpdateBuffer.ProjectName = newUpdatedEntity.GetAttributeValue<string>("name");

                        if (newUpdatedEntity.Attributes.ContainsKey("kdi_project_profile"))
                        {
                            OutputOdataNewUpdateBuffer.ProjectProfile = newUpdatedEntity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("kdi_project_profile").Id.ToString();
                        }

                        if (newUpdatedEntity.Attributes.ContainsKey("kdi_project_type"))
                        {
                            var paymentTypeString = "";
                            try
                            {
                                paymentTypeString = newUpdatedEntity.FormattedValues["kdi_project_type"].ToString();
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                paymentTypeString = "";
                            }
                            OutputOdataNewUpdateBuffer.StatusProject = paymentTypeString;

                        }



                        if (newUpdatedEntity.Attributes.ContainsKey("customerid"))
                        {
                            OutputOdataNewUpdateBuffer.PotentialCustomer = newUpdatedEntity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("customerid").Id.ToString();
                        }

                        if (newUpdatedEntity.Attributes.ContainsKey("kdi_region"))
                        {
                            OutputOdataNewUpdateBuffer.Region = newUpdatedEntity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("kdi_region").Id.ToString();
                        }

                        if (newUpdatedEntity.Attributes.ContainsKey("kdi_projectprofile"))
                        {
                            OutputOdataNewUpdateBuffer.ProjectProfile = newUpdatedEntity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("kdi_projectprofile").Id.ToString();
                        }



                        if (newUpdatedEntity.Attributes.ContainsKey("kdi_cluster"))
                        {
                            var paymentTypeString = "";
                            try
                            {
                                paymentTypeString = newUpdatedEntity.FormattedValues["kdi_cluster"].ToString();
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                paymentTypeString = "";
                            }
                            OutputOdataNewUpdateBuffer.Cluster = paymentTypeString;

                        }

                        if (newUpdatedEntity.Attributes.ContainsKey("kdi_assettype"))
                        {
                            OutputOdataNewUpdateBuffer.AssetType = newUpdatedEntity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("kdi_assettype").Name.ToString();
                        }

                        if (newUpdatedEntity.Attributes.ContainsKey("kdi_productcategory"))
                        {
                            OutputOdataNewUpdateBuffer.ProductCategory = newUpdatedEntity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("kdi_productcategory").Name.ToString();
                        }

                        if (newUpdatedEntity.Attributes.ContainsKey("kdi_totalindex_feasibiltystudy"))
                        {
                            OutputOdataNewUpdateBuffer.TotalIndexFeasibilityStudy = newUpdatedEntity.GetAttributeValue<decimal>("kdi_totalindex_feasibiltystudy");
                        }

                        if (newUpdatedEntity.Attributes.ContainsKey("kdi_revenue"))
                        {
                            OutputOdataNewUpdateBuffer.ProjectedRevenue = newUpdatedEntity.GetAttributeValue<Money>("kdi_revenue").Value;
                        }

                        if (newUpdatedEntity.Attributes.ContainsKey("kdi_projectedmargin"))
                        {
                            OutputOdataNewUpdateBuffer.ProjectedMargin = newUpdatedEntity.GetAttributeValue<Money>("kdi_projectedmargin").Value;
                        }

                        if (newUpdatedEntity.Attributes.ContainsKey("kdi_projectedmarginpercent"))
                        {
                            OutputOdataNewUpdateBuffer.ProjectedMarginPercent = newUpdatedEntity.GetAttributeValue<decimal>("kdi_projectedmarginpercent");
                        }



                        if (newUpdatedEntity.Attributes.ContainsKey("statecode"))
                        {
                            var paymentTypeString = "";
                            try
                            {
                                paymentTypeString = newUpdatedEntity.FormattedValues["statecode"].ToString();
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                paymentTypeString = "";
                            }
                            OutputOdataNewUpdateBuffer.ClosedStatus = paymentTypeString;

                        }


                        if (newUpdatedEntity.Attributes.ContainsKey("actualclosedate"))
                        {
                            OutputOdataNewUpdateBuffer.ClosedDate = newUpdatedEntity.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("actualclosedate");
                        }


                        OutputOdataNewUpdateBuffer.OpportunityId = newUpdatedEntity.Id.ToString();

                    }
                    else if (entity.Type == ChangeType.RemoveOrDeleted)
                    {
                        var removeOrDeletedEntity = ((RemovedOrDeletedItem)entity).RemovedItem;

                        OutputDeleteRemoveBuffer.AddRow();
                        OutputDeleteRemoveBuffer.Id = removeOrDeletedEntity.Id.ToString();

                    }
                }


            }
        }
        while (service == null);
       
    }
```

And here is my Task, so first I get the stored Delta Token. to get only the new data and updated or deleted data, after that, I pass it to the Script Component
[image]

Any suggestion here, why I return an error when I execute it as a package.
the full error goes something like this, I think it returns when trying to set the CreatedOn field but I don't know why, I already give condition only when there is an attribute called created on. And I know the create on is DateTime in Dynamic CRM 365 database and when I tried to execute as a Task there is no Issue.

```
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToDateTime(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ToDateTime(Object value, IFormatProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineBuffer.set_Item(Int32 columnIndex, Object value)
   at OutputOdataNewUpdateBuffer.set_BillingNo(String value)
   at ScriptMain.InputToken_ProcessInputRow(InputTokenBuffer Row)
   at UserComponent.InputToken_ProcessInput(InputTokenBuffer Buffer)
   at UserComponent.ProcessInput(Int32 InputID, String InputName, PipelineBuffer Buffer, OutputNameMap OutputMap)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponent.ProcessInput(Int32 InputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
```

Comment: you can add some logging  and especially the variable which you are converting to DateTime

Comment: I see two lines that deal with datetimes in that code. I suggest you temporarily hard code them to a harmless date and retest. If that fixes it, experiment until you find the line that is the issue. In these situations you can only divide and conquer.

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid, Just to make sure I already commenting on all the code that uses Datetime the error still shows up, and then when I execute as Task it gives me no errors as nothing happens.  Do I get the method correctly using InputToken_ProcessInputRow to put all my code?